# Cast FirebaseListObservable<any> to FirebaseListObservable<MyCustomType>

Tags: angular, typescript, casting, angularfire2

In an angular app, I fetch data from the firebase db like so:

```
  getObjectById(id: string): FirebaseListObservable<myCustomType> {
    return this.fire.database.object('/objects/'+id)
  }
```

This throws the type error `Type 'FirebaseObjectObservable<any>' is not assignable to type 'FirebaseListObservable<myCustomType>'.`

Explicit type casting does not work for the same reason:

```
  getObjectById(id: string): FirebaseListObservable<myCustomType> {
    return <FirebaseListObservable<myCustomType>>this.fire.database.object('/objects/'+id)
  }
```

**How do I get typed objects from my db?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. After posting the question I've seen the problem:

I used `FirebaseListObservable` instead of `FirebaseObjectObservable`.

Firebase**List**Observable → Firebase**Object**Observable.

Comment: How do you push items to a FirebaseObjectObservable ?